# Generate a List with values generated by function in Scala

Tags: list, scala, generator

I must generate some random numbers and sum them. Something like

```
result = generateList(range(0, max), generatorFunctionReturningInt()).foreach(sum _)
```

If `generateList` generates a `List` with size = max and values generated by `generatorFunctionReturningInt`

Or may be something like

```
result = range(0, max).map(generatorFunctionReturningInt).foreach(sum _)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply

```
(0 to max).map(_ => (new util.Random).nextInt(max)).sum
```

where `max` defines both number of numbers and random range.

`foreach` method intended to be used with side-effect functions (like println) which returns nothing (`Unit`).

Answer (score 15):

How about this?

```
Stream.continually(generatorFunctionReturningInt()).take(max).sum
```

Answer (score 11):

The companion objects for various collection types have some handy factory methods.  Try:

```
Seq.fill(max)(generate)
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach is not for returning results, use map instead:

```
val result = Range (0, max).map (generatorFunctionReturningInt).map (sum _)
```

specifically, sum is already predefined, isn't it?

```
val result = Range (0, max).map (generatorFunctionReturningInt).sum
```

working code (we all like working code)

```
val result = Range (0, 15).map (3 + _).sum
result: Int = 150
```

For this trivial case it is the same as `Range (3, 18).sum`.